# Gatling feeder with increment number (not random)

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I'm looking for help to create simple feeder to increment an integer from 0.
I've found lot of feeder example to generate random UUID, Email, Strings...
I've looked at [the doc](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder) 
But nothing for increment a integer (I feel something related to some `new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger(0)` but I can't have something that work), and I'm not looking for creating some CSV or file within "ïnfinite" rows.

So what I have is

```scala
  val userId = Iterator.continually(
    Map("userId" -> CAN'T FIND WHAT TO PUT HERE TO HAVE INCREMENT INTEGER FROM 0
  )

  object CreateUser {
    val createUser = exec(
        http("Create a random user")
          .post("/users"))
          .body(StringBody("""{
            "Username": "Test-${userId}"
          }""")).asJSON
  }

  val httpConf = http
    .baseUrl("https://api.some.site/v1/")

  val users = scenario("Create Users").exec(CreateUser.createUser)

  setUp(
    users.inject(rampUsers(100) during (10 seconds)),
  ).protocols(httpConf)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using AtomicInteger and it worked fine for me:

```
val id = new AtomicInteger(0)
val userId: Iterator[Map[String, Int]] = Iterator.continually(Map("userId" -> id.getAndIncrement()))
```

After that you just need to add the 'feed' method to your scenario:

```
scenario("scenario")
    .feed(userId)
    .exec(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.from(0).map(i => "userId" -> i)` would suffice, Gatling takes care of the feeder thread safety.

Comment: is is possible to combine this method when the map contains multiple key value pairs

val userId = Iterator.continually(Map("userId" -> uuid, "ordinal" -> ordinal))

Comment: @Nimesh, don't highjack an old question. Please create a new and detailed one.